# A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget./Failed assertion: line 380 pos 10: 'data != null'

Tags: json, flutter

I just want to get a weather forecast data from the Internet. I wrote this code below but every time I got the error:

> A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget

For some reason I could not take decoded json data

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'network.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Map<String,dynamic> currentPositionWeatherData;
  String temperature;
  String weatherDescription;
  String name;


  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getCurrentLocationWeather();
    updateUI();
  }

  void getCurrentLocationWeather()async{
    currentPositionWeatherData=await NetworkHelperForWeatherInfo().getCurrentPositionWeatherData();
  }
  void updateUI()async{
    setState(() {
      weatherDescription = currentPositionWeatherData["weather"][0]["description"];
      temperature = currentPositionWeatherData["main"]["temp"];
      name = currentPositionWeatherData["name"];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Text(
          temperature,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
const openWeatherURL="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
const apikey="57aad03f4e48ca815bb1184e74624f46";

class NetworkHelperForWeatherInfo{

  Future getCurrentPositionWeatherData()async{
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
    Response response = await get("$openWeatherURL?lat=${position.latitude}&lon=${position.latitude}&appid=$apikey");
    if(response.statusCode ==200){
      String currentPositionWeatherData = response.body;
      return jsonDecode(currentPositionWeatherData);
    }
    else{
      return response.statusCode;
    }
  }


}

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'homepage.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class LocationFinder{
  bool serviceEnabled;
  LocationPermission permission;

  Future<Position> determineCurrentPosition()async{
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if(serviceEnabled != true){
      return Future.error("Location services are disabled");
    }
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission==LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error("Location permissions are permantly denied,we cannot request permissions.");
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied){
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if(permission != LocationPermission.whileInUse &&
          permission != LocationPermission.whileInUse){
        return Future.error("Location permission are denied/ actual value:$permission");
      }
    }
    Position position =await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
    return position;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
child: Text(
          temperature ?? 'waiting data...',
        )
```

When `_HomePageState` State widget is first built, `temperature` variable will be null (until data is retrieved and the widget rebuilt through `setState` call).  A null value isn't allowed by the `Text` widget which asserts the text value not be null.

The above change will supply the text `waiting data...` when `temperature` is null.

Comment: And in truth, you should be using a FutureBuilder or a FutureProvider to give an alternate widget tree before the Future completes.